# Why does Redlock need to try to acquire the lock in all the N instances sequentially?

Tags: redis, locking

In [Distributed locks with Redis – Redis - The Redlock algorithm](https://redis.io/topics/distlock#the-redlock-algorithm), it says:

> In order to acquire the lock, the client performs the following operations:
>
> 1. It gets the current time in milliseconds.
> 2. It tries to acquire the lock in all the N instances sequentially, using the same key name and random value in all the instances. During step 2, when setting the lock in each instance, the client uses a timeout which is small compared to the total lock auto-release time in order to acquire it. For example if the auto-release time is 10 seconds, the timeout could be in the ~ 5-50 milliseconds range. This prevents the client from remaining blocked for a long time trying to talk with a Redis node which is down: if an instance is not available, we should try to talk with the next instance ASAP.
> 3. ...
>
> ...

I don't understand why it needs to try to acquire the lock in all the N instances **sequentially**. What can go wrong if we try to acquire the lock in all the N instances **in parallel**?

Comment: I don't see anything that can go wrong if you try to acquire the lock in parallel. I'm guessing it was described that way to keep to the simple, step-by-step nature of the description.

Comment: @KevinChristopherHenry A lot of people around me say that it is that way to prevent deadlock. I don't think so, because it will never form a circle.